# Mendeley Reference Manager crashes on start in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, appimage, mendeley

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 (from 20.04) and now my Mendeley Reference Manager AppImage won't start. I made the AppImage executable and confirmed that `libfuse2` is installed. When I try to run the AppImage file from the terminal, I get the following error:

```
(node:10810) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:10810) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
[10810:0820/002523.646076:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Can anyone help with this? Here's a link to the AppImage download in case you are interested: https://www.mendeley.com/download-reference-manager/linux

Comment: I had the same issue on my laptop. It got resolved after I switched to intel graphics instead of nvidia.

Comment: You can also change your nvida driver to the recommended version. For me driver version 515 caused problems but version 510 is working.

Comment: @RoniSaiba: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not ready to give up on my nvidia graphics card just yet (I have a GeForce GTX 1660). I did try your suggestion about changing drivers, but unfortunately the error persists.

Comment: Similar issue: `[27169:0907/120828.102548:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.`  Trying to change drivers gives an error dialog box with no text and just the error icon and "ok" button. @RoniSaiba, how did you switch which card to use?  I too have both an Intel and NVIDIA card.

Comment: @JakeStevens-Haas I use nvidia-optimus to switch between cards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same error message for me (Ubuntu 22.04). Launching the AppImage gives the following error:

```
./mendeley-reference-manager-2.77.0-x86_64.AppImage  
(node:21581) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed. 
(node:21581) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
[21581:0908/111909.638885:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
```

The solution is to launch the AppImage with the following command line arguments:

```
./mendeley-reference-manager-2.77.0-x86_64.AppImage --disable-gpu-sandbox
```

Solution found here: https://forums.balena.io/t/strange-error-message-gpu-process-isnt-useable/357119/2

Comment: aaaand we have a winner!

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04. I also have a Nvidia GPU card. Changing the driver (to 510) did not solve my issue.  I found this solution (install Mendeley via flatpak) that worked (be sure to completely remove the previous version of Mendeley!):

```
$ sudo flatpak install flathub com.elsevier.MendeleyDesktop 
$ flatpak run com.elsevier.MendeleyDesktop
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I will definitely consider this if I decide to revert back to Mendeley Desktop (from Mendeley Reference Manager). Since Desktop is EOL, it seems that a solution for Reference Manager is needed.

Comment: This is not really an answer though. The command installs Mendeley **Desktop**, which is *NOT* the same as Mendeley Reference Manager. It is a previous and now deprecated Mendeley client.