# Mendeley Reference manager install issue with Ubuntu 22

Tags: 22.04, appimage, mendeley

Mendeley recently moved from the Desktop version to "Mendeley Reference Manager."

Link: https://www.mendeley.com/download-reference-manager/

It downloads an AppImage file.  I make the file executable:

```
chmod a+x mendeley-reference-manager-2.77.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

And then try to install it:

```
./mendeley-reference-manager-2.77.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

That gives the following error:

```
(node:13441) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
[13441:0901/105344.492139:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Trying to install using "sudo" gives the following error:

```
[13592:0901/105501.308639:FATAL:electron_main_delegate.cc(253)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Any help?
Gert Kruger

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Mendeley on Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405042/how-to-install-mendeley-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Runs perfectly for me on Ub 22.04. Do you have `libfuse2` installed? It is not installed by default but required for AppImages.

Comment: Similar question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424529/mendeley-reference-manager-crashes-on-start-in-ubuntu-22-04 with suggestion to use the flatpak instead. Report information about your hardware and in particular graphics card: it seems be related with the GPU thus your graphics card. Using nvidia?

Comment: Can one install the libreoffice plugin using the Appimage?

Comment: @24601, no, that question is not relevant here as it relates to Mendeley Desktop, which is no longer available for download and will no longer be actively supported.

Answer (score 4):

*Some* Electron applications packaged as AppImages refuse to launch unless certain *flags* are passed when executing the AppImage.

In the case of Mendeley, you need to append the following Chromium flag.

```
./mendeley-reference-manager-2.80.1-x86_64.AppImage --no-sandbox
```

For reference: [What does the Chromium option --no-sandbox mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68832/what-does-the-chromium-option-no-sandbox-mean)

Comment: This solve my issue when launching mendeley-reference-manager-2.80.1-x86_64.AppImage

Answer (score 0):

Just use `--no-sandbox` flag if you can't see the application. Since some applications are not executable unless this flag is given, same thing happened for R studio previously and worked only if this "`--no-sandbox`" flag is given. But current versions of R studio have this bug fixed and run without this flag. Similarly, Mendeley also has to work on it soon.

> `./mendeley-reference-manager-2.80.1-x86_64.AppImage --no-sandbox`
> For the current version just use the respective version numbers for example, `./mendeley-reference-manager-2.89.0-x86_64.AppImage --no-sandbox`

otherwise, you can always use the desktop version from [mendeley desktop](https://www.mendeley.com/autoupdates/installers/1.19.5) which will be version 1.19.5 for Linux (64-bit). For which run the code from the directory's terminal `./bin/mendeleydesktop`